# JS Regex Pattern dont work

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this method to validate the time in format:
HH:MM-HH:MM

But I always receive false.

This is the method:

```
var cadena="22:40-23:40";
    var patron=/^(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)+-+(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/;
      if (patron.test(cadena))
        alert('Correcto');
      else
        alert('Incorrecto');
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks :)

**EXPLANATION**

I want to check the correct format of the range: HH:MM-HH:MM (Here are two times)
I want to check that the "hours" have two digits between 0-23. And the minutes, have two digits between 0-59.

The both times, should be divided for a "-".

Comment: Your regex requires a range of times. `11:00-22:40`. Did you mean `/^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$/`? Or do you want to validate both - [`/^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d(?:-(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/WS7E03/1)?

Comment: Tip: When your regex is getting too complex (for a human to write and for other humans to read), splitting/parsing and a few comparisons is often a better solution.

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%280%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5Cd%7C2%5B0-3%5D%29%3A%28%5B0-5%5D%5Cd%29%2B-%2B%280%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5Cd%7C2%5B0-3%5D%29%3A%28%5B0-5%5D%5Cd%29%24%2F Your pattern says it needs to be `HH:MM-HH:MM` but you are only passing in `HH:MM` so of course it is not going to match....

Comment: Abraham, could you please explain why you say you use that pattern to validate `HH:MM`? What is your intention?

Comment: Hi! I want to check the correct format of the range: HH:MM-HH:MM (There are two times). I want to check that the "hours" have two digits between 0-23 and the minutes, have two digits between 0-59.The both times, should be divided for a "-".

Comment: try this regex: [0-2]{1}[0-3]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}-[0-2]{1}[0-3]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}

Comment: Then the [answer below does not work for you](https://regex101.com/r/WS7E03/3). Try my suggestions above. Also, try [`/^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d-(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$/`](https://regex101.com/r/WS7E03/4)

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, I finally used the regex of Ankit that you update. Thanks :)

Comment: So, you mean you agree? https://regex101.com/r/WS7E03/4 works for you?

Comment: Im using this /^(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)-+(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/  ,and it works.This is from the answer below that you had edit,no?

Comment: I already explained in the comment above as you won't validate time after midnight.

Comment: Do you refer that don't work after 24:00? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Again, see https://regex101.com/r/WS7E03/3

Comment: Ah okay, I understand what you say. But this is no a problem, because this is for a scheduled table.For example sometimes I need to programming an activity for example between 00:30-04:50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate `HH:MM-HH:MM` you need to have `cadena` value set to `HH:MM-HH:MM` then it works:

```js
var cadena="22:40-10:15";
var patron=/^(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)-+(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/;
if (patron.test(cadena))
  alert('Correcto');
else
  alert('Incorrecto');
  

cadena="22:4440-10:15";
if (patron.test(cadena))
  alert('Correcto');
else
  alert('Incorrecto');
```

Comment: This `^(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)+-+(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$` regex does not validate `00:30-22:40`. And it will validate `21:23232323232323-11:33`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/WS7E03/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does now. Check the updated regex.

Comment: @Abraham glad to help